# why does the IS operator enters an IF statement when false?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I most be missing something here,
see in the image i made of my debug session.

`(items[i] is MailItem)` is FALSE according the debugger, but still it enters the `if` statement.
What am I missing here ?
.

[image]

For reference, here is the full code of this method

```
private MailItem GetMailBySubject(DateTime dateReceived, string subject)
{
    MailItem Result = null;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookIns = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNamespace = OutlookIns.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MAPIFolder myInbox = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);


    Items items = myInbox.Items;
    int count = items.Count;
    MailItem mail = null;
    int i = 1; //DO NOT START ON 0

    while ((i < count) && (Result == null))
    {
        if (items[i] is MailItem)
        {
            mail = (MailItem)items[i];
            if ((mail.ReceivedTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") == dateReceived.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")) && (mail.Subject == subject))
            {
                Result = mail;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192756/discussion-on-question-by-guidog-why-does-the-is-operator-enters-an-if-statement).

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: @EricLippert no its not

Comment: I haven't tested this at all, but it might be a RCW/marshaling issue. See the [Runtime Callable Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper) structure definition and COM Wrappers in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround using [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790156/1364007) provided by Wai Ha Lee. I had to alter it though, because testing if an item is MailItem still behaved strangely.

So I copy the items first into a separate list, and make sure only items of type MailItem are in that list.
The only way I got this filtered is by using `try...catch`, I would still like a better way and I am still curious why the test `if (items[i] is MailItem)` behaves so strangely.

```
List<MailItem> ReceivedEmail = new List<MailItem>();
foreach (var testMail in items)
{
    try
    {
        ReceivedEmail.Add((MailItem)testMail);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

After this I can use the list `ReceivedEmail` without the check on MailItem.

Comment: Still seems... unsatisfying though. Glad you have an answer at least.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yes I dont like this workaround, but for now its all I got

Comment: In newer versions of C# you can directly cast in the if condition: if(items[i] is MailItem mi). Then you can use mi. Not sure though why you should get into the if.

Comment: @RolandBuergi Well that is the million dollar question here :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202881/10103607) SO answer explains a bit about why you are seeing the `IF` condition getting passed even when the expression inside it is `false`. Apparently it's an issue with the debugger and multiple threads. Also, it suggests a workaround to prevent this issue by using `lock`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there is no real working answer in that link. I dont think this applies here